# How to create a master migration class that would call all your migration classes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding

In Laravel the order in which you create your migration and seeders are essential.

When these are run in artisan, if there are any foreign keys in a class(table), and one is executed before the one that is being referenced, the execution will stop, and you get an error.

There is a class called `DatabaseSeeder` that is run when you call php artisan `db:seed`. This class includes all of your seeder classes.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/seeding#writing-seeders

Is there any equivalent for the migrations?

```php
<?php

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            LanguageTableDataSeeder::class,
            UserTableDataSeeder::class,
            PlaceTableDataSeeder::class]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it

**But its Not Recommended**

Step 1:
Run the Command  php `artisan make:migration create_bulk_table`

Now open your migration folder inside the `database/migrations` you will find the new migration `time_stamp_create_bulk_table.php`

open it You will find the Contents like this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBulkTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('bulk', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('bulk');
    }
}
```

How To Do it

There are two methods in this

one is for `creating the table` that is **`up METHOD`**

and

another  one is for `dropping the table` that is **`down METHOD`**

For Example if You want to migrate

`posts` table ,`tasks` table ,`products` table

In Single Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBulkTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        if (!Schema::hasTable('posts')) 
        {

            Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('post_name');
                $table->text('post_desc');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }


        if (!Schema::hasTable('tasks')) 
        {

            Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('task_name');
                $table->enum('task_status', ['Open', 'Closed','Inactive']);
                $table->text('task_desc');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }


        if (!Schema::hasTable('products')) 
        {

            Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('product_name');
                $table->text('product_desc');
                $table->string('product_price');
                $table->timestamps();
            });


        }


    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
        Schema::dropIfExists('tasks');
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');

    }
}
```

**`BE CAREFUL WHILE REFERING THE FORIEGN KEY OF PARENT TABLE  WHICK NEEDS TO BE CREATED BEFORE THE REFERAL`**

For Example  You have column `user_id` in post table  Which you are refering like

```
 $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

`users` table needs to be migrated before the `posts` table

Hope it is clear

Kindly Comment below if you find any bugs

Comment: Thank you Manojkiran A.!

It makes sens to do it like this. It's funny that there is no particular artisan command to make it like the `` DatabaseSeeder ``. It's so convenient!